# Error 207 - invalid column name 'msrepl_tran_version' with Sql Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm setting up transactional replication with updatable subscriptions on Sql Server 2005.  I setup the database with a backup, and haven't changed the schema or even changed the data since making the backup.  I'm getting the following error in my job history:

Error 207: invalid column name 'msrepl_tran_version'

What is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, but not via Google directly.  Transactional publication adds a column named "msrepl_tran_version" to each table in the database.  I took the backup before setting up the replication, so the local copy did not have the msrepl_tran_version column.  Restoring a more recent backup solved the problem.